# Display catalog price with cart rules

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3.7

I have a situation where we give 5% discount on any payment method but credit cards. The one way I found to apply this rule correctly was via Shopping Cart rules.

Thing is, the client wants both the original and the discounted price to be displayed on the catalog and product pages.

I haven't found a way to cleanly do this yet. I tried my hand on catalog prices but then I get two discounts. Please, help a beginner out.

Comment: Shopping cart rules are only applied to products after being added to cart.

Comment: @Zivorad I see, but surely there must be a way to apply a store-wide 5% discount with payment option rules. I could edit price.phtml, but it seems like a really dirty way to do it.